# Selecting rows following a certain flag value in r

Tags: r, pattern-matching, match

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns 'group' and 'value'.  I want to select a max of three rows following the value '4' within each group.  If there is fewer than 3 rows before the beginning of the next group then select just 0/1/2 rows.

Ideally I would get some sort of vector of values of 1/0s or True/Falses to indicate whether I selected the row.

Any ideas?

```
  mydf= structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
 "b"), class = "factor"), value = c(6, 5, 4, 6, 1, 4, 1, 4, 6, 
 6, 7, 3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4)), .Names = c("group", "value"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
  ), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102805578>);
 mydf
```

Comment: There are multiple 4's in each group. Do you want to consider all accurrences? the last? the first?

Comment: yes, I would like to consider all occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been better to show the expected result as well.  May be this helps.

```
 library(data.table)
 mydf[, indx:= cumsum(value==4) , group][, flag:= if (indx!=0) 1:.N %in% 
              2:4 else FALSE, list(group, indx)][, indx:=NULL][]
 #   group value  flag
 #1:     a     6 FALSE
 #2:     a     5 FALSE
 #3:     a     4 FALSE
 #4:     a     6  TRUE
 #5:     a     1  TRUE
 #6:     a     4 FALSE
 #7:     a     1  TRUE
 #8:     a     4 FALSE
 #9:     a     6  TRUE
#10:     a     6  TRUE
#11:     b     7 FALSE
#12:     b     3 FALSE
#13:     b     7 FALSE
#14:     b     4 FALSE
#15:     b     7  TRUE
#16:     b     5  TRUE
#17:     b     7  TRUE
#18:     b     3 FALSE
#19:     b     2 FALSE
#20:     b     4 FALSE
```